# Why rainbow doesn't happen in each drop independently?

Tags: optics

When rainbow happens,we see the rainbow as a whole.

When the light enter each drop,the chromatic dispersion should happen in each drop independently and we should see multiple small rainbows.

So why do we see it as a big one?

Comment: Well, you can if you are looking closely at one raindrop. When you are looking at a billion raindrops 10km away, you see the total response which is the rainbow. Your eyes can not resolve individual raindrops that far away, so resolving each individual rainbow-let isn't happening. You are seeing an averaged medium response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see when you're viewing a rainbow at any particular point is the light from the sun reflecting off droplets at that particular point to hit your eye.  The angle from which the light hits those droplets to get to your eye is always the same, hence all the droplets in that vicinity show one single color.

Next time you see a rainbow, notice how if you move your head, the rainbow moves as well.  This is because the rainbow is always where the light would hit the droplets at the right angle to reach your eye.  Someone from a complete different location would not see the rainbow in the exact same spot if at all.